# On edit how to pre-populate x-editable popup with existing text from a text field inside <a> tag

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, x-editable

I am rendering around 100+ fields after loading data from DB, my intention is to show these fields as normal editable text fields with data in them. 
But when user clicks on any of these fields, An x-editable popup should appear and that it should have the text field's value pre-filled in it (so that user dont have to type everything).

Here is html code:

```
<a href="#" data-type="text" id="abn" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Enter ABN">
 <input type="text" id="abn" name="abn" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $drvData->ABN; ?>" >
</a>
```

in JS i m just doing this:

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
$('#abn').editable();
```

But the problem is that if i set x-editable attribute "data-value" it will show like a href not like a text field. but if I use

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $drvData->ABN;?>" ...>
```

it shows popup as empty, anybody can pls help me, i think it has something to do with .editable() to pass the value on but not sure how to do it.

Comment: so in simple words, its the case of copying (pre-populate) from text field value to x-editable popup, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is the right way to solve the problem but it had worked perfect for me:

Inside the  tag instead of using  i have used  and done something like this:

```
<a href="#" data-type="text" id="ABN" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-placement="right" data-title="Enter ABN">
<textarea id="abn" name="abn" class="form-control" >
<?php echo $drvData->ABN; ?>
</textarea>
</a>
```

and in CSS i have done this to show text area as input field:

```
<style> textarea {  height: 38px;  resize: none;} </style>
```

FYI i m using: `$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';`

I did a lot searching but could not find anything where you can embed an input field inside anchor tag except this work around, I had to make it working so i did it this way :)